# a dynamic dataframe range

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to loop through a dataframe creating a dynamic ranges that are limited to the last 6 months of every row index.

Because I am looking back 6 months, I start from the first index row that has a date >= the first date in row index 0 of the dataframe. The condition which I have managed to create is shown below:

```
for i in df.index:

    if datetime.strptime(df['date'][i], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') >= (datetime.strptime(df['date'].iloc[0], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') + dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=6)):
```

However, this merely creates ranges that grow in size incorporating, all data that is indexed after
the first index row that has a date >= the first date in row index 0 of the dataframe.

How can I limit the condition statement to only the last 6 months of each row index?

Comment: please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you want to do once you have your "dynamic ranges".

You can obtain a list of intervals `(t - 6mo, t)` for each `t` in your `DatetimeIndex`):

```
intervals = [(t - pd.DateOffset(months=6), t) for t in df.index]
```

But doing selection operations in a big for-loop might be slow.

Instead, you might be interested in Pandas's [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) operations. It can even use a date offset (as long as it is fixed-frequency) instead of a fixed-sized `int` window width. However, "6 months" is a non-fixed frequency, and as such the regular `rolling` won't accept it.

Still, if you are ok with an approximation, say "182 days", then the following might work well.

```
# setup
n = 10
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'a': np.arange(n), 'b': np.ones(n)},
    index=pd.date_range('2019-01-01', freq='M', periods=n))

# example: sum
df.rolling('182D', min_periods=0).sum()

# out:
               a    b
2019-01-31   0.0  1.0
2019-02-28   1.0  2.0
2019-03-31   3.0  3.0
2019-04-30   6.0  4.0
2019-05-31  10.0  5.0
2019-06-30  15.0  6.0
2019-07-31  21.0  7.0
2019-08-31  27.0  6.0
2019-09-30  33.0  6.0
2019-10-31  39.0  6.0
```

If you want to be strict on the 6 months windows, you can implement your own `pandas.api.indexers.BaseIndexer` and use that as arg of rolling.